# Dataframe: if value in first column is in a list of strings, replace second column with value

Tags: python, list, dataframe, replace, where-clause

I am trying to implement the following logic on a python dataframe.

If the string value in Column A is in a list that I pre-designated, then replace Column B with the value in Column A.  Otherwise, leave the value in column B as is.

The closest I can get right now is a wonky np.where statement that isn't quite what I want and errors out.  Please see below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Pandas or python? Also rather write out the code than take a screenshot.

Comment: You mean a Pandas DataFrame? Try indexing using [pandas.DataFrame.isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of way in which this can be done. One way and probably the easiest way would be

```
column_to_list = df['A'].tolist()
for index, value in enumerate(column_to_list):
    if value in Other_list:
        df.iloc['B'][index] = value        
    else:
        pass
```

If this meets you expectation let us know and please never post **Photo of codes**

Comment: Replace Other_list with your pre-designated list.

Comment: @PineNuts0 If it solved your problem please accept the answer. In case it didn't let us know so that we can provide better answers